# Extreme value theory: find threshold

Tags: r

I have the code to find the exceedances for a series of returns:

```
bet<-read.csv("Book1.csv")
bet

threshold <- function(bet, n = floor(0.05 * length(as.vector(bet))), 
                      doplot = TRUE) 
{    
  if (class(bet) == "timeSeries") {
    stopifnot(isUnivariate(bet))
  } else {
    bet = as.vector(bet)
  }

  X = rev(sort(as.vector(bet)))
  thresholds = unique(X)  
  indices = match(X[n], thresholds)  
  indices = pmin(indices + 1, length(thresholds))
  ans = thresholds[indices]
  names(ans) = paste("n=", as.character(n), sep = "")

  if (doplot) {         
    plot(x, type = "h", col = "steelblue", main = "Threshold Value")   
    grid()
    rug(as.vector(x), ticksize = 0.01, side = 4)    
    for (u in ans) {
      abline(h = u, lty = 3, col = "red")
    }
  }
  ans
}

## findThreshold -
# Threshold giving (at least) 200 exceedances for Bet:
bet = as.timeSeries(data(bet))
threshold(bet, n = c("monthly", "quarterly"))
```

After running the program, I have the following error:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(time(x)) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

How can it be solved? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What external libraries are you using? `isUnivariate` and `as.timeSeries` are not base functions. I suspect your problem is when you do `as.timeSeries(data(bet))` and has nothing to do with the `threshold` function.

Comment: A small sample of your `bet` data would also be useful.